# Display and pipe only a specific line of text from a stream

Tags: sed, awk, grep, lookup, wordnet

Here is a command line script for a dictionary lookup using Wordnet:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Command line look up using Wordnet - command line dictionary

echo "Type in your word:"
read word

/usr/bin/curl -s -A 'Mozilla/4.0'  'http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s='$word'&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o7=&o5=&o1=1&o6=&o4=&o3=&h=' \
| html2text -ascii -nobs -style compact -width 500 | grep "*"
```

I type in "hello" here is the output:

```
Type in your word:
hello
**** Noun ****
    * S:(n)hello, hullo, hi, howdy, how-do-you-do (an expression of greeting) "every morning they exchanged polite hellos"
```

I only want the string that is after the S:, nothing before it. I want to remove the following:

```
**** Noun ****
    * S:
```

Leaving this for piping by itself ->

```
(n)hello, hullo, hi, howdy, how-do-you-do (an expression of greeting) "every morning they exchanged polite hellos"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a piece of code working which adds to the answer of DigitalRoss:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Command line look up using Wordnet - command line dictionary

echo "Type in your word:"
read word

/usr/bin/curl -s -A 'Mozilla/4.0'  'http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s='$word'&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o7=&o5=&o1=1&o6=&o4=&o3=&h=' \
| html2text -ascii -nobs -style compact -width 500 | grep "*" | sed 's/^[^S]*S://' | grep -v "\*\*\*\* "
```

It removes all the formatting I believe. It removes the `**** Noun ****` lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you alter that `sed -e` to do `s/^.*S:/ /` or perhaps, to be extra careful, `s/^[^S]*S://` you will get what you want. If the sed command is substituting a tab (I can't tell) then you may want to preserve that...

Comment: Removes the S:, but not the  **** Noun **** as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `grep "*"` is intended to do, but you could change it to:

```
grep -Eo '\(.*'
```

Comment: grep "*" - grabs the definitions from the site - else you grab the header - or other useless information.